# Overlapping panel swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to do the following layout, where all JPanels are visible with the exception of panel2 when the program starts. When the user clicks btn1 then JCalendar and panel3 are set to invisible and panel2 becomes visible. The problem I'm having is that panel2 is not showing up with btn1 is clicked. However if i change the borderlayout of panel2 to one that is not being used (in this case WEST) it will show when the button is clicked, but its aligned on the left side and i want it to be centered across the form.

Code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener
{
    private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar calendar;
    private Button btn1, btn2;
    private JLabel label1, label2;

public GUI()
{
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    //panel1 components
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    btn1 = new JButton("Click me");
    panel1.add(btn1);

    //panel2 components
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    label1 = new JLabel("Time:");
    label2 = new JLabel("Date:");
    panel2.add(label1); panel2.add(label2);

    //JCalendar
    calendar = new com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar();

    //panel3
    panel3 = new JPanel();

    //Add panels to JFrame
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(calendar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER); //if i set this to WEST it show!!
    add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //event handling
    btn1.addActionListener(this);

    //hide panel2
    panel2.setVisible(false); 
    pack();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getSource().equals(btn1)
    {
        calendar.setVisible(false);
        panel3.setVisible(false);
        panel2.setVisible(true); //make panel2 visible
        panel2.updateUI();
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

When i click btn1, JCalendar and panel3 is invisible but panel2 does not show

[image]

Comment: Try calling `revalidate` before `repaint`

Comment: it doesn't seem to fix it :( and i have tried calling updateUI() as well

Comment: Consider using a JLayeredPane as your container that holds the overlapping JPanels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues that I can find...

- `BorderLayout` will only ever allow a single component to occupy any given position.  That is, two components can not share the `CENTER` position at the same time, regardless if one is invisible or not.
- You should never call `updateUI`, this is used to tell UI components that the look and feel has changed that they should update in response to it.
- Use `revalidate` to tell the container that some change has occurred to the layout that it should perform a new layout process...

Before click...

[image]

After Click...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener {

    private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;
//    private com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar calendar;
    private JPanel calendar;
    private JButton btn1, btn2;
    private JLabel label1, label2;

    public GUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //panel1 components
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        btn1 = new JButton("Click me");
        panel1.add(btn1);

        //panel2 components
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel("Time:");
        label2 = new JLabel("Date:");

        panel2.add(label1);
        panel2.add(label2);

        //JCalendar
        calendar = new JPanel();//new com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar();
        calendar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        calendar.add(new JLabel("Calendar"));

        //panel3
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        panel3.add(new JLabel("Panel3"));

        panel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN));

        //Add panels to JFrame
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(calendar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //event handling
        btn1.addActionListener(this);

        //hide panel2
        panel2.setVisible(false);
        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource().equals(btn1)) {
            calendar.setVisible(false);
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            panel2.setVisible(true); //make panel2 visible
//            panel2.updateUI();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    }
}
```

Now, I'm pretty sure this won't meet you over all requirements (as I see them)...You have at least two options...

1. Remove the `Calendar` component and add `panel2` to the `CENTER` position when the button is clicked
2. Preferably, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

BorderLayout doesn't do overlapping, IIRC none of the layout managers are about "overlapping layout".

You'll need to do it a different way -- try using JLayeredPane with your existing JPanel & BorderLayout as the bottom layer, and then your (optional) panel as the top layer.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: *"none of the layout managers are about "overlapping layout"* - I don't know about that, I could get `GridBagLayout` to do it ;)

Comment: I liked GridBagLayout.. Gave up on all the other rubbish & just wrote a factory class to generate constraints for that.. years ago now.